# How do you select a single face on a cube in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

This is a very simple question that I cannot seem to find an answer to online. All I want to do is make a selection of a single face in a mesh to apply a material to it. The example image shows a red cube with its GN setup. How do I make that only one face of the mesh is red?
[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Select faces by index.

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Select with distance to another object's geometry.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What would be the node setup for a manual input to select multiple faces? It would be convenient I think to be able so specify it like "0, 1, 2" or perhaps more programmer's style: [0,1,2] to select the faces with equivalent index.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Unfortunately it's not possible to use programmatic expressions of this kind in GN (yet). The way to do it would be to chain "AND" boolean nodes and "EQUAL" compare nodes

Comment: what is the equal node

Comment: @stackers Utilities > Math > Compare node